# Char * array confusion

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX = 4

int main () {

    char *names[] = {
      "Zara Ali",
      "Hina Ali",
      "Nuha Ali",
      "Sara Ali"
    };

    int i = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("Value of names[%d] = %s\n", i, names[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why can one just print `names[i]` instead of `*names[i]`? Could someone provide a memory diagram for clarification?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code or error messages.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/1679849)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format specifier `%s` requires a parameter of type `(char*)`, i.e. a pointer to an array of chars.

In `char* names[]`, each element is such a pointer to an array of chars; after your initialisation, `names[0]` holds a memory address pointing to the begin of string literal `"Zara Ali"`. Thus, it is correct to pass such a pointer as argument to `printf("%s", ...)`.

However, if you write `*names[0]`, then you actually dereference this pointer, yielding a `char`-value, which is in this case `'Z'`. This is just as if you wrote `printf("%s", 'Z')`, such that expected data type `char*` and actual data type `char`  do not match and yield compiler warnings and - when ignoring them -undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a memory diagram is necessary.

Anything in c with * is a pointer in memory.

So,

```
int *a = 3;

a = 3;
*a = memory address

printf("result = %d, result 2 =%d\n", a, *a);
```

output:

```
result = 3, result 2 = 9023923 (this is a random memory address)
```

You must memorize this!

Comment: I understand how this works for ints, but I'm just confused by the char* array.

Answer (score 0):

Char is a single 8bit character, we represent strings in c by having an array of char's of unknown length are using the address of the first char, so for a single string we use

```
char * name
```

Meaning *name* contains the memory address (pointers) of the first character, we can get to the second char by just incrementing the memory address, *name+1*.

If we want an array of strings what we actually do is have and array of memory addresses (pointers) to multiple strings,  So

```
char * names[] = ...
```

is an array of pointers to the first char of a string, you have to specify the number of elements in the c array but because you have supplied it with values, the compiler can infer the number of elements for you.

Each string you point to with each element in *names* can be located anywhere in memory, its just an array of memory addresses, *names[0]* could be equal to 10000 and *names[1]* could be equal to 10, meaning string 0 starts at address 10000 and string 1 starts at address 10, but because the way you have declared it the compiler will most likely have them in memory in order one after the other, but you could later on assign a different memory address to any one of the values.

```
names[2] = "New Values";
```

and the value of *names[2]* will then be the a different location in memory where "New Values" exists and the original string, "Nuha Ali", will still be located in memory at its original location untouched.

If you wanted you could created a char array like so

```
char     names[] = "Zara Ali\0Hina Ali\0...
```

then *names* will be created long enough to contain the entire string and the string will be copied into the array instead of the first char memory addresses of each string being copied into the array. *names* will then just point to a single array of chars and names[1] will return you the second character, and you will not be able to determine where the strings end, any str function will assume the string terminates with the first '\0'.

(Note: your compiler may not let you actually put a string terminator '\0' mid string, I haven't tried it, though I think it should be legal if its not, but you get the idea of how the memory can be layout).

Comment: No assumption that strings terminate with the first `\0` is made; this is true by _definition_ ([C11 §7.7.7/1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1p1)). Also, `"Zara Ali\0Hina Ali\0"` is not a string, but a string literal. A string literal need not be a string ([C11 §6.4.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note78)). Embedded `\0` characters are legal, though.

Comment: printf("%s\n", "abc\0def" ) outputs abc and strcmp( "abc\0def", "abc") == 0.

Answer (score -1):

That is because the `*` is included in the `[]`.
Have a look at [Array subscripting](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.2.1.html):

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))